# My server throws HTTPException but my client receive ServerSOAPFaultException without any useful message

Tags: java, soap, exception, cxf, jax-ws

I have a server hosting soap ws, one operation may throws:

```
import javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException
...
throw new HTTPException(401);
```

but my client receive and logs only this uneseful for him message:

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client
>   received SOAP Fault from server: Fault occurred while processing.
>   Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of
>   the failure.

In other cases I throw a WebServiceException with a message and that message is correctly logged client side, while with HTTPException this doesn't work

I'm using Apache CXF 3.1.11

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769618/soap-serversoapfaultexception-is-thrown-instead-of-appropriate-webfault-excep)

Comment: I've added cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws and cxf-rt-transports-http dependencies in my client project, now instead of ServerSOAPFaultException a SOAPFaultException arrives client side.

I would like only that client can see that there was a 401 error... thanks Michael

Comment: I don't want to throw checked exception org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException, I would like to use the standard javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException and I would expect to see it in client logs... thanks